# getting requested files as an empty array in Laravel API from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-7

here is my javascript form handler
where i get data from the form to send it as request to API

```
import { Store } from './http/requests.js';

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#form_submit').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var formData = new FormData(this);
Store(formData);
 });
});
```

js requests file handler
where i use customized post,get functions to send data with options that i provide on it

```
import { get, post } from '../helper.js';

let pageName = window.location.pathname;
pageName = pageName.slice(1, pageName.length - 5);

export const Store = (value) => {
switch (pageName) {
case 'add_car':
  post('user/create_car', value, true, 'multipart/form-data')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
default:
  break;
  }
 };
```

then the helper file where i use fetch get,post with option that i receive from "requests.js" file and provide it here

```
 import { Local as loc } from './localStorage.js';

 const API_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';

 // token if exists in localStorage
 const token = loc('get', 'token');

 // POST Request
 export const post = (
  url,
  formData,
  auth = false,
  type = 'application/json',
  providedToken = token,
   ) => {
   return fetch(`${API_URL}/${url}`, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify(formData),
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': type,
      Authorization: auth ? `Bearer ${providedToken}` : null,
       },
      })
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((res) => {
     console.log(res);
     return res;
     })
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
       };
```

and finally the Laravel API Cotroller where i tried to debug the issue

```
public function create_car(Request $request)
{
      
   return (response()->json([
        "files" => $_FILES,
        "all Request data" => $request,
    ]));
 }
```

the response i get when i send data from javascript to Laravel API
[image: API Response when submit]

```
 API gives me back this empty object as a response
```

[image: API gives back response]

Comment: The error makes it seem like you are getting traditional form data, but the code you specify is 'application/json'?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat no i debug it and im sure that im sending a form data ... thanks JasonGoemaat

Comment: Hmmm...  Seems like the error "Missing form boundary in multipart/form-data" think it has 'multipart/form-data' and can't find the boundary, but your post sets the type to application/json"...  (`type = 'application/json'`).  What is that for if you're sending form data?

Comment: this is kind of setting default value in function arguments .... my function is post() and it has it's own arguments post(blah1,blah2,balh3) .. this is basic look of function arguments ..... if you want to set a default value for argument ex: post(blah1 = 'something',blah2,blah3) ... balh1 has it default value if you passed a vaue in blah1 one it will changed to due to passed value if u didn't the default value will work automatically

Answer (score 0):

it's seems like **fetch** has a problem ... anyway i just replaced **fetch** library with **axios** and everything runs perfectly

here is what i did on **helper.js** file

```
 // POST Request
 export const post = (
 url,
 formData,
 auth = false,
 type = 'application/json',
 providedToken = token,
  ) => {
   return axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: `${API_URL}/${url}`,
     data: formData,
     headers: {
  'Content-Type': type,
  Authorization: auth ? `Bearer ${providedToken}` : null,
  },
 })
    .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.data;
   })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.data));
};
```